# What's the difference between 'cp -rvf /bin/ ./rmlater/' and 'cp -rvf /bin ./rmlater/'?

Tags: cp

Say I'd like to copy the whole /bin into my ./rmlater folder

- `cp -rvf /bin/ ./rmalter` works as what I want
- But I just found, without the trailing slash of source, `cp -rvf /bin ./rmalter` gives only an empty folder
- However when I tried another source folder without the trailing slash, `cp -rvf ./Desktop ./rmlater/` and it still copys the files

> ```
> debian$ cp -rvf /bin ./rmlater/
> '/bin' -> './rmlater/bin'
> debian$ find ./rmlater/
> ./rmlater/
> ./rmlater/bin
> debian$ rm -rvf rmlater/*
> removed 'rmlater/bin'
> debian$ cp -rvf ./Desktop ./rmlater/
> './Desktop' -> './rmlater/Desktop'
> './Desktop/chrome_via_proxy.desktop' -> './rmlater/Desktop/chrome_via_proxy.desktop'
> './Desktop/chrome.desktop' -> './rmlater/Desktop/chrome.desktop'
> ...
> ```

So any expert could let me know what's the matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`. `/bin` with no trailing slash corresponds to the symlink itself, `/bin/` with a trailing slash corresponds to the target directory.

On top of that, by default `cp` doesn’t follow symlinks when recursing by default. So

```
cp -rvf /bin/ ./rmalter
```

copies the directory (and its contents), but

```
cp -rvf /bin ./rmalter
```

only copies the symlink.